# How big a react page can be before memory becomes an issue?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, reactjs

I know this is a loaded question, but I wonder if anyone experienced any memory issues with large React pages, i.e., many components? I'm thinking maybe infinite scroll or lots of list/table data...

If so, then what was the page like? How many components you had? What was the issue and how did you solve it?

Comment: this is more based on the skill of the person writing code as opposed to react having memory issues.. make sure you clean up when you are finished with objects, react has its own cleanup but you can add to it with `componentWillUnmount` to remove event listeners you had or anything else.. if you are loading tons and tons of rows into the DOM with an infinite scroll your browser will eventually start to slow down because its so much on there (this is not react specific) so to improve speed you can look at only rendering a chunk of the data at a time and the rest is not loaded into the DOM

Comment: @JohnRuddell, yes. I totally understand that it's more of a developer issue, but still, what is the order of magnitude for a good developer to start seeing issues? 10,000-100,000?

Comment: You shouldn't be loading 10000 rows into into the Dom.. I personally wouldn't render more than a hundred or two hundred.. Anything more than that and you should start removing the first rows rendered... Like an infinite scroll... Or do paging and render 25 at a time